# Improve performance of SqlBulkCopy with an IDataReader on IEnumerable<object[]>

Tags: c#, performance, sqlbulkcopy

I am refactoring some code that extracts data from dynamic Excel Spreadsheets or from a CSV file in the source format of an IEnumerable and then saves this using ADO.NET's SqlBulkCopy. It is currently taking nearly 43 seconds to save 500,000 rows of data. The original code converted the IEnumerable to a DataTable before passing it to SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt). This conversion process as well as the saving of the data was also quite a lot of time. The Target table to Bulk Copy into is freshly created before the bulk copy with no data and no indexes (but with 2 default constraints. I have tried turning these off). After reading various articles (including using FastMember ) about speed improvements using a Forward Only DataReader (IDataReader) to prevent loading the whole object in memory I thought I would implement my own for IEnumerable. I managed to reduce the preparation time of the MyDataReader> to just over a second, but then I noticed the SQLBulkCopy going bananas. All the time I saved had been shifted but this time inside the SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt) function. I can see its being called 11 times which corresponds to 11 batches of 50000 rows. It looks like it is thrashing trying to read and write each individual row and column value running it 4.6 million times. I thought an IDataReader was meant to be fast? How do I make this faster?
 Code and dotTrace below:

**Example Source Data**

```
EnumerableDataReader<object[]>
EnumerableDataReader[0] = object[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5"}
EnumerableDataReader[1] = object[]{"Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4"}
EnumerableDataReader[2] = object[]{"Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4"}
```

**IDataReader Implementation**

```
public class EnumerableDataReader<T> : IDataReader
    where T : IEnumerable
{
    private IEnumerator<T> _iterator;

    public EnumerableDataReader(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        this._iterator = list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _iterator.Dispose();
    }

    public bool Read()
    {
        return _iterator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }


    public Type GetFieldType(int i)
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<object>)_iterator.Current)?.ElementAt(i).GetType();
    }

    public object GetValue(int i)
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<object>) _iterator.Current)?.ElementAt(i);
    }

    public int GetValues(object[] values)
    {
        values = (object[]) (IEnumerable<object>)_iterator.Current;

        return values.Length;
    }

    public int FieldCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _iterator.Current != null ? ((IEnumerable<object>) _iterator.Current).Count() : 0;
        }
    }
```

**Saving code:**

```
    public void bulk_copy_data(string destinationTable, IDataReader dt, int fieldCount, FieldMappingInfo fi)
    {
        try
        {
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(Connection(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null))
        {
            bulk.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
            bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 500;
            bulk.BatchSize = 50000;


            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount - 1; i++)
            {
                bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping() { SourceOrdinal = i, DestinationOrdinal = i });
            }

            bulk.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
```

**dotTrace Output**
[image: dotTrace output]

Comment: Have you tried to store `_iterator.Current` as `IEnumerable<object>` to avoid casting every time? Also, if `_iterator.Current` is not a `List<>`, those `ElementAt(int i)` may hurt.

Comment: Sorry ran out of screen room for the dotTrace, GetValue is run 4.6 million times but is taking 2.3 seconds which is 2.19% of the total time. So will definately update it, but its not the biggest source of time.